# Input freeze/lag for a few seconds on Mac Mini M1

Tags: macos, mac, freeze, input, delay

I have a M1 Mac mini base model (8 GB RAM, 256 GB drive with 90% filled) that I have been using daily for past week or two. I's pretty much my **first real work experience with Mac**, since I was a Windows user.

Occasionally when I hit shortcut or even an ordinary key (it happened with letters O, C) for e.g. closing a tab in Chrome, typing a message in Slack, searching for a project in Toggl, the keyboard and mouse freezes for like 2-4 seconds. After it unfreezes, the keys are pressed and action is taken.

Also hitting Caps Lock freezes the inputs in the same way, but I'm not sure if it has the same cause.

It's pretty annoying, I don't know that from Windows

I know I tinker with the system quite a lot and usually have like 5 GB of swap, but I have to have many apps running in the background to make MacOS usable for me. My startup apps:

Karabiner Elements (modifier keys changed + 10 Complex modifications) - this problem happens even if it's not running.

- Rectangle Pro
- Middle click
- F.lux
- Toggl
- Shottr
- Alt Tab
- Maccy
- Google Drive
- Logitech Options
- Dropover
- Alfred
- iStatistica

I've got around 20-30 tabs in Chrome opened and ~5 GB of swap. I'm on Monterey 12.6.1.

Do you please have an idea how to fix the freezing? Thanks!

Comment: really, you bought a machine to small for your needs. Full RAM *and* full drive will sow everything down. You also have a hoggy browser [Chrome] & a slew of 'helpers' sitting on the interrupts all the time. If you're constantly running 5GB swap, that's a clear sign you don't have enough RAM. The M1s are supposed to be fast on swap, but personal experience is that once you choke the RAM they get choppy. Smallest Mac in the building is a 16GB M1 iMac & it chokes as soon as look at it compared to the 10 years older Mac Pros with 64GB.

Comment: I used 8GB Mac Mini because it's spare at my work and I didn't know if I'll benefit from the switch to Mac. My realationship with MacOS goes up and down. In the up moment, I bought a Macbook Pro 16GB 1TB HDD, which I still haven't unboxed because I've been hesitating if MacOS is for me and now also if 16GB will suffice. I use just Chrome and office apps 90% of the time, sometimes a graphic editor or a Docker instance for local web development.

32GB Mac is out of my budget. But I could return this Pro and get M2 24GB RAM 512GB HDD for $100 less. I wanted the Pro because I use 2 monitors.